# Update python dictionary (add another value to existing key)

Tags: python

I have simple dictionary with key, value:

```
d = {'word': 1, 'word1': 2}
```

I need to add another value (to make a list from values):

```
d = {'word': [1, 'something'], 'word1': [2, 'something1']}
```

I can't deal with it. Any clues?

Comment: You can't deal with it *how*? Please show what you did try. You need to replace the current value with a list object.

Comment: `d['word']=[d['word'],'something']`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Well you can simply use:

```
d['word'] = [1,'something']
```

Or in case the `1` needs to be fetched:

```
d['word'] = [d['word'],'something']
```

Finally say you want to update a sequence of keys with new values, like:

```
to_add = {'word': 'something', 'word1': 'something1'}
```

you could use:

```
for key,val in to_add.items():
    if key in d:
        d[key] = [d[key],val]
```

Answer (score 22):

You could write a function to do this for you:

```
>>> d = {'word': 1, 'word1': 2}
>>> def set_key(dictionary, key, value):
...     if key not in dictionary:
...         dictionary[key] = value
...     elif type(dictionary[key]) == list:
...         dictionary[key].append(value)
...     else:
...         dictionary[key] = [dictionary[key], value]
... 
>>> set_key(d, 'word', 2)
>>> set_key(d, 'word', 3)
>>> d
{'word1': 2, 'word': [1, 2, 3]}
```

Alternatively, as @Dan pointed out, you can use a list to save the data initially. A Pythonic way if doing this is you can define a custom defaultdict which would add the data to a list directly:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> d[1].append(2)
>>> d[2].append(2)
>>> d[2].append(3)
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: [2], 2: [2, 3]})
```

Comment: `defaultdict` FTW

Answer (score 12):

It will be easiest if you always use lists, even when you just have a single value. It will just be a list of length 1.

```
>>> d = {'a': [1], 'b': [2]}
>>> d
{'a': [1], 'b': [2]}
>>>
>>> d['a'].append(5)
>>> d
{'a': [1, 5], 'b': [2]}
```

Comment: Mind that the original dictionary uses scalars, not lists.

Answer (score 3):

You can create your dictionary assigning a list to each key

```
d = {'word': [1], 'word1': [2]}
```

and then use the following synthases to add any value to an existing key or to add a new pair of key-value:

```
d.setdefault(@key,[]).append(@newvalue)
```

For your example will be something like this:

```
d = {'word': [1], 'word1': [2]}
d.setdefault('word',[]).append('something')
d.setdefault('word1',[]).append('something1')
d.setdefault('word2',[]).append('something2')   
print(d)
{'word': [1, 'something'], 'word1': [2, 'something1'], 'word2': ['something2']}
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me without the need to import anything or setdefaults python3

```
gear = {
    'Cameras': ['77D','SL2'],
    'Lens': ['10mm','18-55mm', '50mm', '70-250mm'],
    'Mounts': ['Monopod', 'Tripod']
}
def dump(dictionary):
    print('Camera Gear: \n')
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        print(key, value)
dump(gear)
gear['Mounts'].append('Gimbal')
dump(gear)
```

[output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZpXJ.png)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for help. I did it that way (thanks to Willem Van Onsem advice):

```
x = (dict(Counter(tags))) #my dictionary
for i in x:
    color = "#%06x" % random.randint(0, 0xFFFFFF)
    x[i] = [x[i], color]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do. I hope it helps. If you have a lot of items to add to your  dictionary this may not be the fastest route.

```
d = {'word':1, 'word1':2}

d['word']=[1, 'something']

d['word1']=[2, 'something1']

print(d)

{'word': [1, 'something'], 'word1': [2, 'something1']}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try the below:

`d['word'] = [1, 'something']`

`d['word1'] = [2, 'something']`

call `d` now

Hope this helps!