# Add new data to existing dictionary

Tags: python

I want to add new data in the existing dictionary. I tried using update but it is not working for me. What to do?

Code:

```
comp_data = {}
temp = form.competition.data
print('\nTemp: ', temp)
for i in temp:
    print('i : ', i)
    comp_data.update(i)

print("\n\nComp Data : ", comp_data)
```

Output:

```
Temp:  [{'question': 'q1', 'option1': 'q1', 'option2': 'q1', 'option3': 'q1', 'answer': 'q1'}, {'question': 'q2', 'option1': 'q2', 'option2': 'q2', 'option3': 'q2', 'answer': 'q2'}]

i : {'question': 'q1', 'option1': 'q1', 'option2': 'q1', 'option3': 'q1', 'answer': 'q1'}
i : {'question': 'q2', 'option1': 'q2', 'option2': 'q2', 'option3': 'q2', 'answer': 'q2'}


Comp Data :  {'question': 'q2', 'option1': 'q2', 'option2': 'q2', 'option3': 'q2', 'answer': 'q2'}
```

The output i want is like this:

```
Comp Data :  {{'question': 'q1', 'option1': 'q1', 'option2': 'q1', 'option3': 'q1', 'answer': 'q1'}, {'question': 'q2', 'option1': 'q2', 'option2': 'q2', 'option3': 'q2', 'answer': 'q2'}}
```

Comment: Dictionaries can’t have duplicate keys and the output you say you want is not a dictionary.

Comment: this is possible? add dictionary in the main dictionary like this : {{'key':'value'}, {'key':'value'}}

Comment: `{{'key':'value'}, {'key':'value'}}` is not a dictionary, it looks like a `set`, but sets can't contain dictionaries because they are not hashable. Try putting that into a python interpreter and read what it says. You *could* make a list of dicts: `[{'key':'value'}, {'key':'value'}]`. It seems like that's what you are starting with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have your desired output in `temp`

```
Temp:  [{'question': 'q1', 'option1': 'q1', 'option2': 'q1', 'option3': 'q1', 'answer': 'q1'}, {'question': 'q2', 'option1': 'q2', 'option2': 'q2', 'option3': 'q2', 'answer': 'q2'}]

Comp Data :  {'question': 'q1', 'option1': 'q1', 'option2': 'q1', 'option3': 'q1', 'answer': 'q1'}, {'question': 'q2', 'option1': 'q2', 'option2': 'q2', 'option3': 'q2', 'answer': 'q2'}
```

Dictionary is not a typical container that you can index , it works on the principles of `KEY` --> `VALUE` pairs and cannot contain duplicate keys

I would suggest you to directly use `temp` for your further usage in your code

Based on your edit -

if you still want to create a new dictionary you can do that as follows -

```
>>> t = [{'question': 'q1', 'option1': 'q1', 'option2': 'q1', 'option3': 'q1', 'answer': 'q1'}, {'question': 'q2', 'option1': 'q2', 'option2': 'q2', 'option3': 'q2', 'answer': 'q2'}]
>>> d = {}
>>> 
>>> 
>>> for i,k in enumerate(t):
...     d[i] = k
... 
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(d)
{0: {'answer': 'q1',
     'option1': 'q1',
     'option2': 'q1',
     'option3': 'q1',
     'question': 'q1'},
 1: {'answer': 'q2',
     'option1': 'q2',
     'option2': 'q2',
     'option3': 'q2',
     'question': 'q2'}}
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

If by that you want to update an existing key then you can simply use

```
d['i'] = [1,"something"]
```

see [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41825868/update-python-dictionary-add-another-value-to-existing-key) for more info

but if what you mean is that you want to add a new key to existing dictionary then There is no explicitly defined method to add a new key to the dictionary. If you want to add a new key to the dictionary, then you can use assignment operator with dictionary key.

see [This link](https://www.journaldev.com/23232/python-add-to-dictionary#:%7E:text=There%20is%20no%20explicitly%20defined,assignment%20operator%20with%20dictionary%20key.&text=Note%20that%20if%20the%20key,the%20value%20will%20be%20overwritten.)for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want

```
comp_data = []
temp = form.competition.data
print('\nTemp: ', temp)
for i in temp:
    print('i : ', i)
    comp_data.append(i)

print("\n\nComp Data : ", comp_data)
```

which gives you a replica of `temp` (a list).
Or

```
comp_data = {}
temp = form.competition.data
print('\nTemp: ', temp)
ik = 0
for i in temp:
    print('i : ', i)
    ik++
    comp_data.update({ik: i})

print("\n\nComp Data : ", comp_data)
```

which gives you a dict.