# add key and value in json dict

Tags: python, json, django, dictionary

how add key and value from user in file?
def register():

```
while True:
    username=input("enter your username: ")
    if not username.strip():
        print("\")
        continue
    if username in user_data:
        print("this user exist")
    else:
         break

while True:
    password=input("enter your password: ")
    if not password.strip():
        print("\")
        continue

    renter_pass=input("enter again")
    if password !=renter_pass:
        print("pass and \pass should be equal!")
    else:
         break
while True:
    age=input("enter your age: ")
    if not age.strip():
        print("\")
        continue
    if not age.():
        print("input must be number ")
        continue
    else:
        break
```

the age not dump with key and my dict "y": ["1470", "12"]}
dosnt have age key

Comment: Does this line not give you an error: `print("\")`? Something like `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal`. If you want to print a backslash you need to escape it so you should use `print("\\")`

Comment: In addition to what @AbdulAzizBarkat said, your question is confusing. Does this post explain what you want to do? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41825868/update-python-dictionary-add-another-value-to-existing-key

Comment: How did you save those variables to dict?

Comment: @simon in json file

Comment: @mehrdadkml, the code has several mistake and doesn't seem to related to what you want. what is `user_data`? what is `y`? where and how will `username`, `password` and `age` be stored after this code?